# Conditional using JOLT ( if - then - else )

Tags: json, conditional-statements, jolt

Good morning.

I was wondering if it is possible to use JOLT to compare keys from a json. The main ideia is doing a simple conditional (if-then-else) using jolt.

Please, take this json as an example:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "AUTH_ID": "RAFAEL",
      "INVOICEID": 1110225,
      "AUTHORIZEID1": "PAUL",
      "AUTHORIZEID2": "RAFAEL",
      "STATE": "OK",
      "MESSAGE": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to do this comparisson:

```
IF AUTH_ID = AUTHORIZEID1
THEN MESSAGE = "OK"
ELSE
IF AUTH_ID = AUTHORIZEID2
THEN MESSAGE = "OK"
ELSE
MESSAGE = "NOT OK"
```

Would you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The correct json in the end will be like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "AUTH_ID": "RAFAEL",
      "INVOICEID": 1110225,
      "AUTHORIZEID1": "PAUL",
      "AUTHORIZEID2": "RAFAEL",
      "STATE": "OK",
      "MESSAGE": "NOT OK"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no possibility to make conditions, especially those more complicated. The only way is to do sth like in this example: http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#andrewkcarter2